# Unit test spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, mocking

I have this spring boot class (imports and business logic omitted for brevity)

```
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class  TokenService {

    private String token;
    private final RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    private JsonNode getApiToken() {
      ...
      ...
        return Optional.of(someResponseEntity);
    }

    public synchronized String getToken() {
        if (token == null) {
            log.info("No token, refreshing...");
            JsonNode response = getApiToken();
            if (response != null) {
                token = response.get("access_token").asText();
            }
        }
        return token;
    }
}
```

and it's unit test (also redacted):

```
public class TokenServiceTest {

    @Mock
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @InjectMocks
    private TokenService tokenService;

    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetToken() {
        String accessToken = "your-access-token";
        String responseBody = "{\"access_token\":\"" + accessToken + "\"}";
        ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(responseBody, HttpStatus.OK);

        when(restTemplate.exchange(eq("https://example.com/token"), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(), eq(String.class)))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);

        String token = tokenService.getToken();

        assertEquals(accessToken, token);

        verify(restTemplate).exchange(eq("https://example.com/token"), eq(HttpMethod.POST), any(), eq(String.class));
    }
}
```

The unit test runs but it actually sends the post request to the endpoint, which is not desirable when running tests. How can I modify the test class so that requests are actually not sent?

kind regards

I tried refactoring the service to use a singleton of Resttemplate which I can override but the results are the same: an actual call is sent to the api

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `RestTemplate` as a bean in your serivce like so:

```
 @Autowired private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

EDIT:
You're not required to use @Autowired since you have `@AllArgsConstructor`, just need to have the field declared but not initialized.

Since @InjectMocks only injects mocks by constructor or properties, but in your case you're initializing yourself in the service.

As a side note, you should extract the logic for the `RestTemplate` request outside of your service since this way you have both web request logic and business logic in the service and it becomes difficult to unit test down the road.
Think about extracting the web request logic for fetching the token to a different client class - e.g. `ExampleServiceClient`. Then you can autowire that class to your service, mock the whole web request logic and only test the business logic.